# Polynomial moment matching problem

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, polynomials

Consider the polynomial function $P_N : [0,1] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ given by $P_N(x) = \sum_{r=0}^N c_r x^r$. For $k=0,1,2,\ldots$ define the $k$th moment of $P_N$ by $$\mu_k = \int_0^1 x^k P_N(x) \,\mathrm{d}x.$$

I want to find the coefficients $c_0,\ldots,c_N$ so that the first $N+1$ moments $\mu_0,\ldots,\mu_N$ are equal to some (known) numbers $b_0,\ldots,b_N$ respectively.

The obvious way to solve the problem is to compute the definite integral above to get $$\mu_k = \frac{c_0}{k+1} + \frac{c_1}{k+2} + \cdots + \frac{c_N}{k+N+1}, \text{ } k = 0,\ldots,N$$
so that we have a system of $N+1$ linear equations in $N+1$ unknowns. The system is given by $$H \mathbf{c} = \mathbf{b}$$ where $\mathbf{c} = (c_0,\ldots,c_N)$, $\mathbf{b} = (b_0,\ldots,b_N)$ and $H$ is the square [Hilbert matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert_matrix) of order $N+1$.

The downside of this approach is that the Hilbert matrix is 'nearly singular', and for $N>10$ its inverse contains numbers so large that they cannot be accurately represented on modern computers (using the double precision data type in C for example).

I therefore want to know other methods that can be used to solve the above polynomial moment matching problem for large $N$.

Since the problem statement is quite simple, I would be very interested to know if this is problem is already known and if there is any published literature on the subject.

Comment: Write $P_N$ as a linear combination of Chebyshev polynomials, and evaluate the  Chebyshev moments $\mu_i'$ accordingly.  The resulting system of linear equations might be better conditioned than the Hilbert matrix system.

Comment: @kimchilover Thank you, this is helpful. The resulting matrix is better conditioned, and can be inverted for $N \leq 60$ using a double precision data type. Please write an answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write $P_N$ as  a linear combination of Chebyshev polynomials, and evaluate the Chebyshev moments $\mu_i'$  accordingly. The resulting system of linear equations might be better conditioned than the Hilbert matrix system.

This amounts to *preconditioning* by a linear change of variables.  The
choice of Chebyshev polynomials is somewhat ad hoc, but it is intuitively plausible.  They are orthogonal with respect to a particular weighting function on the interval; perhaps, now that you have an approximation to your answer you might pick a better weighting function and corresponding system of orthogonal polynomials.

Comment: To add to the answer, the shifted Legendre polynomials work well too (the matrix is numerically invertible for $N \leq 30$). Neither Laguerre nor Bernstein basis polynomials are useful. Of all the basis polynomials I checked, Chebyshev polynomials of the 2nd kind are the most useful (i.e. have the best conditioned matrix).